# Spark Scala scala.util.control.Exception catching and dropping None in map

Tags: scala, exception, apache-spark, rdd

I am writing a Spark app in scala and want to handle a dirty input file.

```
// CSV file
val raw_data = sc.textFile(...)

val clean_data = raw_data.map(_.split(delimiter))
  .map( r => (r(0), r(1).toDouble)
```

will throw a NumberFormatException when r(1) isn't a number. This happens on a small number of rows in the ugly input data.

I finally landed on an ugly way to accomplish what I need:

```
import scala.util.control.Exception._

val clean_data = raw_data.map(_.split(delimiter))
  .map( r => (r(0),
        catching(classOf[NumberFormatException]).opt(r(1).toDouble))
  .filter( r => r._2 != None)
  .map( r => (r._1, r._2.get))
```

This leaves me with two questions.

1) What is the best way to simply drop malformed rows in the map?

2) How can I handle the Option types created by catching without needing to first explicitly filter out None and then map and apply the .get function on the non-None Option values?

I attempted applying a .flatMap(identity) step to rid myself of the Nones, but got an expected: TraversableOnce[?] exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Spark `collect(pf:PartialFunction)`is the twin brother of the scala collections `collect` that exists with exactly that purpose: keep those elements of the collection that are defined at the partial function.

```
val rawData = sc.textFile(...)

val cleanData = rawData.map(_.split(Delimiter))
             .collect{ case Array(x,y) if (Try(y.toDouble).isSuccess) (x,y.toDouble) }
```

Another option, that does not evaluate the `.toDouble` twice would be to use flatMap:

```
val cleanData = rawData.map(_.split(Delimiter))
                       .flatMap(entry => Try(entry.toDouble).toOption)
```

Note: In Spark is a bit confusing that there's a parameterless `collect` method that is meant to get data from the RDD to the driver.

Comment: Ok, after some fiddling I got this solution to work (e.g. Array(x,y) was making x and y Any, so instead I just did (x, y) to preserve them as strings). But I have some questions. 

First, it just seems a bit strange to have to call .toDouble twice --- once to check if it's toDouble-able and once to actually do it.

Secondly, for this case, .collect() works well because I can pull the RDD into memory on the driver. But what would I do in the cases where I was actually dealing with big data and couldn't use .collect()

Thanks for the help!

Comment: re: `collect` I know it's confusing. There're two `collect` methods on RDD. The parameterless version `def
collect(): Array[T]` triggers the computation and delivers all data  to the driver.  The version that takes a partial function: `def
collect[U](f: PartialFunction[T, U])(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): RDD[U]` is the equivalent of the Scala `collect` function on collections and produces another RDD as result, so it's still as parallel as any other RDD transformation.

Comment: rd: toDouble (x2) - I use it because I prefer the partial function version, but indeed, it executes twice the operation. Here's an alternative: `data.flatMap(entry => Try(entry.toDouble).toOption)`

Comment: I updated the answer for the sake of future visitors